# How can I add visible information to C# classes using attributes?

Tags: c#, attributes, design-time

I am trying to add information to a C# interface, and I am trying to add this information using attributes.

Say for example, that I have int parameters everywhere, and some of these int parameters are "row IDs" and some are "column IDs".  I'd like to be able to do this:

```
namespace RowIdTest1
{
    using System;

    public class Class1
    {
        public int Get([RowId] int r, [ColumnId] int c) { return 3; }
        public void Set([RowId] int r, [ColumnId] int c, int x) { return; }
    }

    [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class RowIdAttribute : System.Attribute { }

    [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class ColumnIdAttribute : System.Attribute { }
}
```

so that when another programmer uses my DLL and browses to Class1 in Visual Studio,
he or she would see this in the "Class1 (from metadata)" window:

```
namespace RowIdTest1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1();

        public int Get([RowId] int r, [ColumnID] int c);
        public void Set([RowId] int r, [ColumnID] int c, int x);
    }
}
```

When I try it, the attributes don't appear at all.

I know you can do this sort of thing with ///-comments.

I know that you can use the System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute class on anything (although descriptions on methods will appear but descriptions on parameters will not appear).

Am I doing something totally weird with C# attributes? Inappropriate? Insane?

Comment: Why not just name your variables descriptively? public int Get(int rowID, int columnID) and add comments to denote what row and column actually come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I doing something totally weird with C# attributes?

Yes.

You are trying to use an attribute to express a *business domain* fact about the parameter. That's not what attributes are for.  Attributes are for expressing facts about the *programming language mechanism*.  That is, when you say:

```
[Obsolete]
class BlackAndWhiteTelevision {}
```

That is saying that **the class itself** is obsolete and that you should no longer use it because **the class** has been replaced with a different class. Do not use the obsolete attribute to state that **the physical world thing that the class represents** can no longer be manufactured and sold at a profit.

That a particular parameter represents a row identifier is a fact about the *business* of your method, not about the *mechanism* of the method. You should put attributes on method parameters that express things like "this parameter has a default value" or "this parameter should be marshalled by value when called via COM interop" or "this parameter is going to be written to before it is read from" -- those are facts about the parameter *as a variable in a programming language*, rather than facts about how the parameter *models some concept in your business process*.

For more thoughts on how to use attributes to express facts about mechanisms instead of business domains, see my article on the subject and the comments to it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/02/properties-vs-attributes.aspx

Comment: Eric, while what you say is true about some custom attributes, there are many commonly-used attributes that don't fit this pattern. MVC's validation attributes come to mind, as well as the attributes used by unit testing frameworks. The fact that the PersonId property is `Required` is a business-level notion, but it is still useful to represent it with a custom attribute, right?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Your example illustrates my point nicely. You would not put the `[Required]` attribute on a field called "CS440AlgorithmsAndDataStructures" in a class "ComputerScienceDegree" *to document the fact that class was required in order to obtain the degree*. That's a fact about the *business domain* of the program, not a fact about *the field*. You put that attribute to say that the *mechanism* that deserializes or data binds or whatever the heck it does, is required to provide a value for this field.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Similarly with `[Fact]` in unit testing. You don't put `[Fact]` on `const double Pi = 3.1415926535;` just because that is a fact; that's the *business* of the program. You put `[Fact]` on a method to say "the unit testing framework is going to use this method as part of the testing mechanism". That's the *mechanism* of the program.

Comment: Eric, I agree with @StriplingWarrior. I have seen a lot of code where attributes are used for something other than programming language mechanism. E.g. Lot of people use 'Description' attribute to provide description for their Enum member which is displayed in UI. OR worse, they are used to specify business rules in numerous ORMs. E.g. http://goo.gl/EdhCX .

Comment: The attributes page on MSDN describes common usages (http://goo.gl/TYFQc) and they clearly follow the guideline that attribute should be about programming language mechanism and not business rules. I think the linked Attributes page could be updated to make it clear that it's not a good idea to use attributes for business logic.

Comment: To clarify, I agree with the point you made. I was only saying that there are lot of developers who use attributes for what they are not intended for. I dislike attributes for business logic mainly because they do not lead to clear code as you have to use reflection.

Comment: I guess I'm having difficulty determining at what point you cross the line: If a `[Required]` attribute is a fact about the `FirstName` field, does that extend to the `[Display(Name="First")]` attribute? In what way is saying "the rowId parameter represents the ID of a Row" any more business oriented than saying "the rowId parameter [CanBeNull]" (a la Resharper). You can see from my answer that I actually agree with you in substance: I'm just trying to wrap my brain around the *business domain vs programming mechanism* argument.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I hear ya. Personally, I think [Required] is a business domain rule and should not be specified using attribute. Eric, what are your thoughts on Data Annotations in Silverlight? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(v=vs.95).aspx I think it is in clear violation of what you posted.

Comment: I've seen many people abuse attributes re: enums as well, and that's a horrible practice.  How are you going to localize that string?  It would be more appropriate to put a resource ID there, and then we're back in the domain of a programming mechanism-- What do I use to look up a string corresponding to this?

Answer (score 4):

> Am I doing something totally weird with C# attributes? Inappropriate? Insane?

In general, the reason to use attributes is because you want to have certain information about a class or its members available to your program via reflection at runtime. This isn't in keeping with that idea, so I'd say it's an inappropriate use of attributes.

I think a more preferred way to give the programmer a subtle hint that you want the parameter to represent a rowId is to use the parameter name:

```
public int Get(int rowId, int columnId)
```

Couple this with /// comments, like you mention, and you have a pretty effective way to tell consumers of your class what your expectations are.

Finally, if you really want to prevent users from accidentally providing the arguments in the wrong order, you could leverage strong typing.

```
public struct RowId {
    private int _rowId;
    public int Value{get{return _rowId;}}
    public RowId(int rowId) {_rowId = rowId;}
}


public int Get(RowId rowId, ColumnId columnId)
```

This would make it nearly impossible for someone to accidentally mix up the inputs. (Note that I am not recommending this pattern: It introduces a lot of overhead for very little benefit.)

Comment: OK, I get the point of attributes now. I was actually looking for something like C++'s "typedef int RowId;" so that every RowID parameter in the eventual interfaces (much larger than the example, of course) would have a marker indicating what kind of int is required for the parameter.

Comment: @NullPointersetc.: That would be roughly why my `struct` example does. The `RowId` type would behave in most ways the same way as a special type of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Why not just name the arguments

```
public int Get(int rowId, int columnId)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I don't understand this very well. Is it common that users of your library (I assume) have to decompile your classes to look at the metadata? Why not just write some XML documentation for the interface and ship it with your library instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's "insane".  If it isn't working as is, maybe, assign the attributes to nested items inside of some kind of data structure, and then maybe pass the data structure as a parameter to the function.  Just one idea.